# Convert inner join sql query to linq

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a sql query which is to be converted to Linq

```
Select b.title
from TableA as a
inner join TableB as b
on a.Email=b.Email
where a.Title<>b.Title
```

the query which i have tried  is

```
var query =from s in TableA
          join r in TableB
          on r.Email equals s.Email
```

but not able to replicate the where clause which may include many columns

My requirement is i need to compare the 2 tables on a primary key column and then get the other column values which do not match

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You want to get the rows where a.Email = b.Email but the condition says the opposite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a "select" at the end of the query, and you need to get the inputs in the right order:

```
var query = from s in TableA
            join r in TableB on s.Email equals r.Email
            where s.Title != r.Title
            select s.Title;
```

For multiple columns, use an anonymous type:

```
var query = from s in TableA
            join r in TableB 
              on new { s.Email, s.Foo } equals new { r.Email, r.Foo }
            where s.Title != r.Title
            select s.Title;
```

Comment: It looks similar to inner join but what about the where clause ? the query above will retrieve all the common values. I need to compare on primary key and get the other columns which does not match

Comment: @praveen: Sorry, I missed the where clause - that would just be a where clause... will edit.

Comment: Probably a silly question why can't i use <> in place of != in the  where clause .  When i use <> variables s or r are out of context